# android testing - EditText returning empty even when it has characters

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, automated-tests

I'm trying to perform a functional test on an EditText, sending text to it by first gaining focus on the field using the following snippet:

```
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         editText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

and then sending the string via:

```
instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
instrumentation.sendStringSync("Some Text");
instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
```

If I run the test and watch it, the text is really being input into the EditText, but when I try to get it for use in an assertion, the EditText returns an empty text:

```
assertFalse(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty());
```

I've tried logging the text, but it really returns an empty string, as if there is no text in the EditText. I have also tried running the assertion on a separate Runnable or after a certain delay to no avail.

**Temporary solution:**
As for the meantime, I'm passing the test by manually adding

```
editText.setText("Some Text");
```

before the assertion, though I think there could be a better or correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Another work-around I've found is by using Android Espresso. After sending string to the EditText via the instrumentation, I can assert its validity via:

```
 onView(withText("Some Text")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```